# Supporting QGIS 2. 14 in Windows 10

Tags: qgis

My laptop is Windows 10. Can I install QGIS 2. 14 ? If not which version will support Windows 10?

Comment: Have you tried? And why don't you want the latest version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now (**2018-10-28**) current versions of QGIS are 2.18.25 old LTR and 3.4 LTR. See https://www.qgis.org

Version for Windows 10 is [available](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html).

Comment: QGIS 3.4 (also a LTR) was released today

Comment: Thanks for your notes. http://blog.qgis.org/2018/10/28/qgis-3-4-madeira-is-released/
Updated answer